# Further optimizing my Java code filled with for-loops

Tags: java, performance, for-loop

I wrote a code that returns two prime numbers with their gap equal to a given `long` and having no other prime number between them.

These are the methods I've made so far:

```
public static long[] firstGap(int gap, long lLimit, long uLimit) {
    for(long i=lLimit; i<=uLimit; i++) {
        for(long j=i+1; j<=uLimit; j++) {
            if(isPrime(i) && isPrime(j) && j-i==gap && !repeatedIsPrime(i+1,j-1)) {
                return new long[]{i,j};
            }
        }
    }
return null;
}
```

For checking if a number is prime

```
public static boolean isPrime(long n) {
    for(int i=2;i<n;i++) {
        if(n%i==0) {
            return false;
        } 
    }
return true;
}
```

For checking if there's a prime number between two numbers

```
public static boolean repeatedIsPrime(long x, long y) {
    for(long i=x; i<=y; i++) {
        if(isPrime(i)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
return false;   
}
```

What I've done so far is having the loop index as int but then I'd have a lossy conversion, next is reducing the method invocations but I can't find a way to do that. The only improvement I've made so far is that I've removed some unnecessary storing and assigning of values, other than that I got nothing. So how do I further optimize my code?

Comment: You can make this program vastly faster by improving your algorithms first. Reducing method invocations isn't going to make this code faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code:

```
public static long[] firstGap(int gap, long lLimit, long uLimit) {
    for(long i=lLimit; i<=uLimit; i++) {
        if(isPrime(i)) {
            long j = gap + i;
            if (isPrime(j) && !repeatedIsPrime(i + 1, j - 1)) {
                return new long[]{i, j};
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

First, if isPrime(i) == false, other check isn't have any sense. Second, `for(long j=i+1; j<=uLimit; j++)` can be deleted, because you use only one j (when j-i==gap)

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the inner loop: `if (isPrime(i) && isPrime(i+gap) && !repeatedIsPrime(i+2, i+gap-2) return new long[]{i, j}
2. Make sure lLimit and uLimit are odd and increment by 2 as no sense to check the even numbers
3. When checking for prime, run till square root of n
4. Can use HashMap<Long, Boolean> to make sure you only check the same number once - but will have to remove the smallest number as you move
5. Use smarter primality test, such as e.g. Fermat test https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Fermat_primality_test for faster isPrime(i)